# Match two values in different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am making a simple WebSockets chat, and have two arrays (this is server side, Node.js):

```
var clients = {1: "info about 1", 2: "info about 2", 3: "info about 3", 4: "info about four", 5: "info about five", 6: "info about six"};
var partners = [[1,3], [2,6], [5, 4]];
```

Now what I need to do, is look up a clients partner, in the partner array. So, for example, if my script returned `4`, it would need to look up `4`, and return `5`, and if my script returned `1`, it would return `3`.

I tried just using `partners[mynumber][0]` but the problem is that `mynumber` could be either of the values, rather than just the first one.

Comment: Can a client have multiple partners, or are the numbers guaranteed to be unique in the `partners` array?

Comment: is there a possibility to make `partners` associative as well? i mean the keys are unique anyways, right? Otherwise loop through array so that each value is that small array-pair, and check keys.

Comment: @ExplosionPills A client can only have one partner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to look for that particular array first:

```
function partnerOf(someId) {
  var res;
  for (var i = 0, l = partners.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (partners[i][0] === someId) {
      res = partners[i][1];
      break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

... but it looks (and is) quite cumbersome. An alternative would be to reorganize `partners` structure, turning it into an Object:

```
var partners = {
  1: 3,
  2: 6,
  5: 4
};
```

Then look-up becomes trivial: you just evaluate `partners[someId]`, that's all. Both more readable and way faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
var possiblePartners=partners[mynumber];
var partnerNum=(possiblePartners[0]==myNumber)?possiblePartners[1]:possiblePartners[0];
```

However, the best thing to do would be to have an associative array with your partners, like this

```
var partners={1:3,2:6,5:4};
var partnerNum=partners[mynubmber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.prototype.different = function(arr2) {
    var ret = [];
    arr2.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        if(arr2.indexOf( this[i] ) > -1){
            ret.push( this[i] );
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Use like this

```
console.log(yourArray1.different(yourArray2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of your data to allow easy partner finding

```
// defined partners DB
var partners  = {};

// adds a chat from c1 to c2
function addChat(partners, c1, c2){
    partners[c1] = c2;
    partners[c2] = c1;
}
function findChatPartner(partners, c1){
    return partners[c1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop combined with an if/else statement

```
for (var i = 0, n = partners.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (partners[i][0] === mynumber)
        return partners[i][0];
    else if (partners[i][1] === mynumber)
        return partners[i][1];
}
```

It iterates through each set of numbers in the array until it finds `mynumber`, then returns the other number in that set